# How can i return a structure/array from a class-function to my main-function?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, structure

I hope someone can help me!

I just want to return a structure/array from my class-function to my main program-functions.

But I always get an error:

```
CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyClass.MyStructerInClass[]' to 'MyMainProgramm.MyStructerInMainProgramm[]
```

Code is simple and hopefully self-explaining:

```
class MyClass
{
    public struct MyStructerInClass
    {
        public string string1;
        public string string2;
        public int int1;
        public int int2;
        public int int3;
        public double double1;
        public double double2;
        public DateTime time1;
    }

    public MyStructerInClass[] NewStructerInClass = new MyStructerInClass[100];

    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public MyStructerInClass[] MyFunctionInClass()
    {
        //do some stuff

        return NewStructerInClass
    }       
}

namespace MyMainProgramm
{
    public struct MyStructerInMainProgramm
    {
        public string string1;
        public string string2;
        public int int1;
        public int int2;
        public int int3;
        public double double1;
        public double double2;
        public DateTime time1;
    }

    public MyStructer[] NewStructerInMainProgramm = new MyStructer[100];

    private void MainFunction()
    {
        NewStructerInMainProgramm = MyClass.MyFunctionInClass();
        //Here Error: CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyClass.MyStructerInClass[]' to 'MyMainProgramm.MyStructerInMainProgramm[]'                       
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that. Even though both structs have the same fields they are different types and are not castable to one another. I guess your best bet would be to use the same struct, or if it is not possible to copy each individual field from one instance to another.

Comment: Thx for the comment! I fixed that by using classes instead of stucters.